# tensorflow can not work with zeppelin

Tags: tensorflow, apache-zeppelin

on the server which installed zeppelin, Anaconda and tensorflow, it runs well.But when I want to scratch code on the zeppelin like below:

```
%python
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
```

and run this code, I met such error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/hadoop/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/hadoop/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 71, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.framework_lib import *
  File "/home/hadoop/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/framework_lib.py", line 73, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import Graph
  File "/home/hadoop/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import registry
  File "/home/hadoop/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/registry.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import tf_logging as logging
  File "/home/hadoop/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/tf_logging.py", line 53, in <module>
    if _interactive:
NameError: name '_interactive' is not defined
```

how to solve this.I didn't google this solution.

Answer (score 0):

At last, I fix the file

> /home/hadoop/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/tf_logging.py

like this:

```
# If we are in an interactive environment (like jupyter), set loglevel to info
# and pipe the output to stdout
if True:
#if _interactive: 
  _logger.setLevel(INFO)
  _logging_target = _sys.stdout
else:
  _logging_target = _sys.stderr
```

and restart the zeppelin's python interpreter. It works fine!

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in the tensorflow project about this : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/8420

They fix it by instatiating _interactive with a default value of False

```
# If we are in an interactive environment (like jupyter), set loglevel to info
# and pipe the output to stdout
_interactive = False
if _interactive: 
  _logger.setLevel(INFO)
  _logging_target = _sys.stdout
else:
  _logging_target = _sys.stderr
```

The best is to update tensorflow as soon as the bugfix will be including in a release, or update /site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/tf_logging.py as they did it in the above mentionned commit.

Regards,
Loïc